# I am getting a java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1 while gradle upgrade to version 3.1.4

Tags: java, android

I had my **gradle version 2.2.3** recently I tried updating it to **3.1.4** but it gave me error

> `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1`

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'.

  > java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':nuswypedev:processDebugResources'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
      at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:57)
      at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
      at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
      ... 29 more
  Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
      at com.android.ide.common.symbols.SymbolIo.readTableWithPackage(SymbolIo.java:133)
      at com.android.ide.common.symbols.SymbolIo.readTableWithPackage(SymbolIo.java:127)
      at com.android.ide.common.symbols.SymbolUtils.loadDependenciesSymbolTables(SymbolUtils.java:183)
      at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:830)
      at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:797)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:491)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:249)
      at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
      ... 39 more

Comment: Can you paste your code please

Comment: Updated my logs as this happening while project gradle sync so I am not sure which part of my project is giving me this error

Comment: @karishma Did you found any solution for this? I am facing same issue.

Comment: @jay Try adding  org.gradle.jvmargs='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' in your main project's gradle.properties file. 
This resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Fixed at plugin version to 3.4.0-alpha08 wrapper version to 5.1-rc-1

Comment: That's a good start but jumping from Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version 2.3.3 directly to the latest alpha is dangerous. Perhaps start with 3.0.0 first and gradually migrate forwards. Also some versions of AGP are only compatible with some versions of Gradle (this is why you got the error). AGP 3.1.4 for example works fine with Gradle 2.14.1.

Comment: That's fine but on moving from 2.2.3 to 3.0.0 I was getting the same MalformedException so I had to wait for gradle to release a new version to fix this issue